# Running scripts automatically as you save in vim

Tags: python, vim

I am new to vim and am figuring out how to run a script automatically as I save a python file in vim. I got the solution https://github.com/ahw/vim-hooks  but that is not the working.

Here is my script that has to run in the terminal

> echo autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive --aggressive $3.py

$3 is the path to the file without the extensions. This script corrects the syntax according to pep8 documentation. Name by which it is saved is .py.bufwritepost.vimhook.sh

It is saved locally where the file that needs to be corrected is save.

As I save a file in vim this script doesnt run.

Any suggestions or solutions I should try ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the code

```
map <F5> :w\|!python %<cr>
```

to the vimrс. Save and run with F5 launch.